# securely pass data to AS3 from mySQL

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I need to pass private data from MySQL to a flash file securely.  I have a PHP script that is assigning variables on the server side - how do I pass this to flash without being available publically?  I assume XML and an HTTP query string are out of the question because of security.  What's the most secure way of doing this?

Thanks!

Basically I have some file paths that I need to load into a music player - however, I don't want these URLs to be publicly known.  I was hoping I could pass data directly to flash securely somehow.

Alternatively, should I be storing these documents as local file for flash rather than URLs?

Comment: I imagine you could use a HTTPS connection... otherwise define "most secure"...

Comment: I need to load some files into flash (mp3) that are available for listening but wouldn't otherwise be available to the public internet.  What's the most secure way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass "private" data to the client, he'll be able to read/decrypt it no matter what you do.

Comment: I need to load some files into flash (mp3) that are available for listening but wouldn't otherwise be available to the public internet. What's the most secure way of going about this?

Comment: You can give the file the most obscure name ever, you can create a copy of the file to be streamed and delete it once playback has finished - but no matter what you do, any streamed file can be downloaded (saved). Infact, software like Charles makes it a walk in the park. The best thing you can do is obscure the file name on the server, stream the MP3s through a PHP script and only allow access to the files if their referrer matches your flash (swf) url. But this can be faked too.

Answer (score 0):

use htaccess and mod rewrite to dynamically create the filename based on something random that the flash can pass to your server

or

create a PHP session for the user and echo the file contents using PHP, if the session doesn't exist then PHP can just exit